# Can an attacker change the src attribute in an iframe?

Tags: asp.net, html, security

I have a website that uses `IFrame` in a page that loads other pages based on server side logic. So, if I do a View source, I would see something like this:

```
<iframe src="DeterminedOnServerSide.aspx" id="myFrame">
</iframe>
```

My question is - Is there any way, an attacker can change the `src` attribute to point other users to a malicious website considering that the `src` is determined on the server side?

Comment: Can you post sample code as to how the page to load is determined?  If it's read from something like a query string, then it can certainly be tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes or no. You have not specified how "DeterminedOnServerSide.aspx" is determined. If your code for this consists of `DeterminedOnServerSide = Server.Request["frame"]` then it can clearly be 'hacked'. If you use a method that ensures only valid urls are chosen, then it is not vulnerable.

Comment: +1 This is the only answer so far that is correct, imo.  You need to know what code is determining the page to load in the iframe before you can say definitely "yes" or definitely "no."

Answer (score 0):

The page you "include" using the IFRAME can navigate to a new page, changing the source.

Any user of the site can change the src value of the IFrame, using Developer tools like Firebug and IE Developer Tools

Any sucsessful man in the middle attack can change all your html source including the src attribute. If the attacker is in control of a proxy or network between your customer and your server they can change any of your html including the src attribute.

Any sucsessful hack into your server can change all you sourcecode and change the attribute.

What Hacker are you thinking of? you should only iframe to people/sites you trust, as this is a common way for cross site scripting attacks.

Answer (score 0):

No, not unless they've compromised your server and can access and modify those source files. And *if* that's the case, changing of the 'src' attribute in the iframe is the least of your worries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A XSS attack has the capability of changing the src of an iFrame.

Check it out: http://research.zscaler.com/2009/12/xss-embedded-iframes.html

Comment: ... but only if the page is vulnerable to XSS

Comment: "Is there any way, an attacker can change the src attribute " - The answer is yes. There is a way. It's isn't exclusively true because it can be protected against, but there IS a way.

Answer (score 0):

The only ways to change the src attribute of your iframe (or anything in your website) are:

1. The webpage which load the iframe has an XSS vulnerability and the attacker use the DOM to change it.
2. He (or she) get access to your source code. Then the change of a iframe attribute is your less important concern ;-)